# Why PDO does not bind my params?

Tags: php, pdo, parameters, bind, defined

I have a query with some parameters that I bind with PDO. This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT altezza_pneumatici FROM tbl_catalogo_pneumatici "
     . "WHERE sigla_produttore = :marca "
     . "AND larghezza_pneumatici = :larghezza"
     . "GROUP BY altezza_pneumatici "
     . "ORDER BY altezza_pneumatici ASC";

$query = $DBobj->dbConn->prepare($sql);
$query->bindValue(':marca', $marca, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':larghezza', $larghezza, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

But it does not work. I have this error:

> **Warning**:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in **C:\Users\mydoc\Documents\pjct\web_gomme_new\class\class.Pneumatico.php** on line **116**

What is the problem? I printed both variables used in binding function, and they have correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not say for sure if this is the problem, but there is an error in your query. (missing space).

```
$sql    = "SELECT altezza_pneumatici FROM tbl_catalogo_pneumatici "
        . "WHERE sigla_produttore = :marca "
        . "AND larghezza_pneumatici = :larghezza[ ]"
        . "GROUP BY altezza_pneumatici "
        . "ORDER BY altezza_pneumatici ASC";
```

See the brackets behind :larghezza.

Your query will end up being "..AND larghezza_pneumatici = :larghezzaGROUP BY altezza_pneumatici...".

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I made this mistake! :D Thanks, it was exactly my problem.

Comment: NP :) It happens. Do accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it though. Stackoverflow likes "answered" questions. (otherwise it will be considered unanswered forever)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to break up the SQL query string.

```
$sql = "SELECT altezza_pneumatici FROM tbl_catalogo_pneumatici 
        WHERE sigla_produttore = :marca 
        AND larghezza_pneumatici = :larghezza 
        GROUP BY altezza_pneumatici 
        ORDER BY altezza_pneumatici ASC";
```

Is fine. Whitespace at end of each line. This should do the trick.

Comment: Actually his current method conforms with well-used naming conventions. Ie. the Zend Naming convention: http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Coding+Standards (search for "String Concatenation")